# Generate buttons in loop using php

Tags: php, sql, loops, button, dynamically-generated

I am currently programming on a webapplication for capturing contact data.

It works to show a table from a mysql database (see SELECT statement).
Now I want to dynamically generate buttons for deleting particular rows from the database.
It works to show the buttons but they are not working.

I take the variable $id to name the different buttons "rowButton1", "rowButton2" and so on.
In the next step I would like to delete the row if the button is clicked.

How do I address a button in a particular row in the if statement below?

```
            $res = mysql_query("SELECT id, type_id, title, visible FROM field ORDER BY step, pos");
            echo '<table border="1">';
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
                $id = $row['id'];
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['type_id'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['title'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['visible'] . "</td>";
                echo('<td><input type="submit" name="rowButton'.$id.'" value="Delete"/> </td>');
            }
            echo "</table>";

            if(post('rowButton'.$id) =="Delete"){
                    $del = mysql_query("DELETE FROM field WHERE id=$id");
                    echo'<p>Entry was succesfully deleted</p>';
            }
```

Comment: What does `post()` do?

Comment: You have to create a form in loop too if you want just PHP-only.

Comment: You should use PHP to generate the buttons.  But use JavaScript to handle what happens when it's clicked.

Comment: Sorry, here the post function:                                 function post($key){
 return(isset($_POST[$key]) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST[$key]) : "");
   }

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have to specify via javascript what happens when the button is triggered (i.e. get id of button, then ajax call to your php script), then in a separate script process the deletion. Right now I think you're mixing the frontend and backend of your website. [A brief explanation of frontend vs backend](http://www.codeup.com/different-types-of-programmers-front-end-vs-back-end/).

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your `if` inside of your `while` along with a few other tweaks ...

```
        $res = mysql_query("SELECT id, type_id, title, visible FROM field ORDER BY step, pos");
        echo '<table border="1">';
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
            if(post('rowButton'.$row['id']) =="Delete"){
                $del = mysql_query("DELETE FROM field WHERE id=" . $row['id']);
                $deleted = '<p>Entry ' . $row['id'] . ' was succesfully deleted</p>';
            } else {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['type_id'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['title'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['visible'] . "</td>";
                echo '<td><input type="submit" name="rowButton'. $row['id'] .'" value="Delete"/> </td>';
                echo "</tr>";
            }
        }
        echo "</table>";
        echo $deleted;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Important Points :**

1 )The code you posted has a starting `<tr>` tag but it never ends

2) If you are generating rows and columns with buttons then what actions should buttons do should be handled by JavaScript ,  jQuery.

3) You did not mention what your `post()` is doing so it is not clear that why or how would it return a string "Delete"

**What you should do??**

1 )give every button a unique id when you are creating them which in your case would be `id` you are getting from mysql

2) also insert `onmousedown = "some_function(this.id)"` in your button tag

3) In the function get the `id` of the row you want to delete

4) send it to php via jQuery `$.post()`

5) get the id in php plug it into your sql query to delete the row

and your done !! 
hope you got it

Answer (score 0):

In PHP submit input type will execute a php file which amntioned `<form>` tag. [See](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp)

And all data you want to send to php file that will be executed must be between form tag.
For example:

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="extraction.php" method="post">
    Number 1: <input type="text" name="en1"><br>
    Number 2: <input type="text" name="en2"><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<form action="sum.php" method="post">
    Number 1: <input type="text" name="sn1"><br>
    Number 2: <input type="text" name="sn2"><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

In first from block the form tag will execute extraction.php file with passing en1 and en2.
In second form block the tag will execute sum.php file with passing sn1 and sn2.

You can't pass en1 or en2 values to sum.php and likewise can't pass sn1 and sn2 to extraction.php.

So basically you need a form tag for each line or use JavaScript `onclick` trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use

```
 if(isset($_POST['rowButton'.$id]))
 {    }
```

in place of

```
if(post('rowButton'.$id) =="Delete")
{   }
```